# How did Rabbi Aryeh Kaplan write so many books?

Tags: rabbis, writing-printing, authorship, torah-writing, rabbi-aryeh-kaplan

Aryeh Kaplan wrote some 50+ books in the span of a decade or so. Obviously he was remarkably talented at writing, but I'm just curious how exactly was this possible. He's often quoted as saying in the foreword of his books (written by the editors) "I use my physics background to analyze and systemize data, very much as a physicist would deal with physical reality." Also, you'll notice in almost all of his books is a VERY detailed index.

Any info on how he did it?

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya Nathan and thanks for this first question. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: This question might be closed as it doesn't really relate to Judaism (see [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) but don't let that deter you from asking or answering more questions)

Comment: A Jewish academic scholar, [Jacob Neusner](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacob_Neusner), is known for having authored hundreds of books. Many of his books are simply revisions or reorganizations of previous books.

Comment: Aryeh Kaplan's most amazing accomplishments are The Living Torah and the Torah Anthology translation (Yalkut Me'Am Lo'ez.) The amazing thing about The Living Torah is the amount of detail he goes into concerning not only the textual translation from traditional sources but also information from non-traditional sources, for example he obviously asked an Egyptologist about the translation of Poti Phera. So the question seems more to be, how did he physically have the time to do all of this. I would imagine he was capable of multiple simultaneous processing, like Rb Chaim Ozer Grodzinski.

Comment: +1 to the question. @Harel13 many (most?) of Professor Neusner's books are just translations of Rabbinic literature--often poorly done. Anyone could crank those out. Rabbi Kaplan's works are much more thorough, original, and researched. His main translation project--MeAm Loez--involved teaching himself Ladino, and I believe he also did original research and analysis to add footnote with sources, explanations, etc.

Comment: Apparently he was very, very smart.

Comment: Why was this Q closed? Mi Yodeya has many questions about the personages and approaches of Rabbis. This doesn't seem that different from asking "what was the Mechaber's process in writing the Shulchan Aruch" or "why didn't the Gra write more books," both of which I feel would be on-topic.